# Please help identify late 80's/early 90's movie: "Catfish" scams women

Tags: identify-this-movie, drama, crime

Lead (Caucasian) male in his 30’s (akin to John Terry or Jack Wagner) wins the trust of a (Caucasian) woman early in the movie, and feigns an investment opportunity for her.

She is mid-30’s, single, shoulder-length blond hair, well-dressed in a dark blue blazer and skirt, her character may have been a travel agent.

He collects $25,000 in cash from her, and uses the cash to buy a used, gray Rolls Royce sedan from another (Caucasian) man (Nicholas Pryor, possibly, but his filmography doesn’t confirm this).

I thought the actress might be Markie Post, Shelley Hack, or Donna Mills, but their filmographies don’t confirm this.

The Rolls is a tool to give the appearance of wealth.

I recall the leading man bilks women out of their money, with any love interest being secondary.

I believe there is at least one other woman he bilks, but he eventually gets caught.

A drama, most likely made-for-TV, between 1988 and 1994, and aired on a weeknight in primetime on ABC/CBS/NBC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This movie is "Highway Heartbreak" 1992 made-for-TV starring Heather Locklear and John Schneider.  No keywords for it are on IMDB; I found it as its teleplay was written by the same author as "The Man with Three Wives" (1988, TV).  Thanks to all who viewed this!